# how to build tensorflow with bazel right?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, installation, bazel

When I run my python code I get the error message `AttributeError: module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'float32'` I don't get this message when I install tensorflow using pip however, if I use pip I get another error message because I can't install the models package with pip, so I have to build tensorflow from source. I installed bazel and then I ran the configure.py file. I answered all the question that were asked about the build of the file. I don't know if this is important but at the end I got this message:

```
Preconfigured Bazel build configs. You can use any of the below by adding "--config=<>" to your build command. See tools/bazel.rc for more details.
        --config=mkl            # Build with MKL support.
        --config=monolithic     # Config for mostly static monolithic build.
```

I thought I would have finally fixed the problem after days of trying to fix it because the program didn't crash or something, just this message. But when I run my python program I still get the same error. This question is mainly if I built it wrong, but also if I this error is really because I need to build tensorflow, and if I can somehow add the models package to the package that is downloaded using pip. I have been trying to fix this for quite a long time and I don't know what to do anymore.

Comment: Please include the traceback from the AttributeError exception, and the snippet of your code where this is failing.

Comment: Oh I forgot many things when I wrote this. I am using windows 10 and python 3.6.2
This is the error message 

  `File "C:\Users\user2\Desktop\captchasolver\project.py", line 18, in <module>
    from object_detection.utils import ops as utils_ops
  File "C:\Users\user2\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\object_detection\utils\ops.py", line 291, in <module>
    dtype=tf.float32):
AttributeError: module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'float32' `


And this is line 18 of project.py: `from object_detection.utils import ops as utils_ops`

Comment: do you have any files named `tensorflow.py` in your project? The usual source of errors about missing attributes or methods is that a module with the same name is shadowing the real one.

Comment: @2five Is your issue resolved now? Did you try the steps as mentioned [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/source#install_bazel)?